# Im get hacked? Why my Iphone opened port 49152

Tags: ios, iphone, apple

[image]

i dont understand why my iphone opened port 49152

apple said this port for dynamic

i searched on google for several days but i found nothing about this

i also factory reset for my iphone but this port still opened (iphone 11)

can i close this port ?  i worried about my privacy

Answer (score 0):

The TCP port range 49152-65535 is used as an alternative for interaction with iTunes over the network when the primary TCP port (3689) is not available. This is entirely normal and there is no reason to try to close it.